# The model already has an element that has the same name - ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, error-handling

I'm working with ASP.Net web application and whenever I tried to add a `FOREIGN KEY` this error appears in the Data tools operations :

> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name
>   dbo.FK_Sellers_Users. SQL71508 :: The model already has an element
>   that has the same name dbo.FK_Sellers_Users.

I don't understand what's the problem with FK! I have 2 tables with this error

table `Sellers` :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sellers] (
    [Seller_ID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [SUsername]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [SEmail]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [City]          NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginDate] DATETIME      NULL,
    [CreatedDate]   DATETIME      NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Seller_ID] ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sellers_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([SEmail]) REFERENCES [Users]([Email]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Sellers_Users] FOREIGN KEY ([SUsername]) REFERENCES [Users]([Username])
);
```

and table `Users` :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       INT           NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [UserType] INT    NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Users_Username] UNIQUE ([Username]), 
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Users_Email] UNIQUE ([Email]),
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right there in your CREATE TABLE statement for dbo.Sellers, you have two FK constraints named FK_Sellers_Users.

Make those names unique, perhaps by adding the column name on the end.

Comment: do you mean like FK_Sellers_Users_Email ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  Or use whatever naming convention you want, so long as it results in unique names.

Comment: now i have another error : ` The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Sellers_Users_Email". The conflict occurred in database , table "dbo.Users", column 'Username' `

Comment: I don't know what your ALTER TABLE statement is.  You should probably just drop the entire table and recreate it if you can, or if you can't for some reason, you need to drop the FK first then add it back with the new name.

Comment: thanks i did it but still the same , i should only change the names in `Seller` table right ? and nothing in `Users` table ?

Comment: You don't need to change the column names in the table at all, just the Foreign Key names.  Every constraint should have a unique name.  The FKs on your Users table already have unique names, so no need to change those.  Your FKs on your Sellers table don't have unique names, so you do need to change those.

Answer (score 0):

You have two foreign keys with the same name `FK_Sellers_Users`. You should better use `FK_Sellers_Users_Email` and `FK_Sellers_Users_Username`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this has to do with data that was already entered. Some of the PK and FK data that were entered before might have the same values. You need to delete those first and make the changes you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools), you probably have a foreign key defined in a folder for Keys.  Look in "DB Name\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Tables\Keys."

Then Look in the table definition.  "DB Name\Schema Objects\Schemas\dbo\Tables".  The key could be defined in BOTH places.