# Can't add table to SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2015

I am learning C# from a book and trying to add 2 tables to a database. I have created the database and I click on the table and select add table. I fill in all the columns and then save the table with a new name. Nothing happened, so I pressed the update button and then the table was added to the database explorer on the left.

The tab at the top says `dbo.Table_1.sql`

When I create the next table and click the update button I get the following error:

> SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.Table.

Comment: Czech this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082167/the-model-already-has-an-element-that-has-the-same-name-asp-net

Comment: Put your create statement in your question description.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have two tables with the same name: "Table". 
The name of the script file and the name of the table are not the same. There are a couple ways to see/edit the name of the table. First open the script file that you want to change.

Normally you have the designer on top and the T-SQL tab on the bottom. The T-SQL tab will contain something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    ... other columns ... 
)
```

You can directly edit the SQL in that pane if you want.

Alternatively, you can click in the designer pane and then press F4. This shows the Properties pane for the table. The very first item in the properties pane is the "(Name)" which specifies the name of the table.

Change your second table to have a different name from your first table and you should be able to save it without getting the error.

Answer (score -1):

I also came across this issue, and it resolved by running the CREATE TABLE statement via NEW QUERY instead of NEW TABLE

Comment: This does not address the real problem (which the already given answer does).